# Help required in configuring Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2003

We have an application which uses VS.NET 2003 and Crystal Reports version 9.1.5000.0
We are migrating this application into a different server.
We had reconfigured each and every report with the new connection details and in the process of reconfiguration we had changed all the SQL Server DB connection details to new server.

But when we tried configuring a report which has a sub report that takes data from FILE SYSTEM Data its throwing the following error.

UnExcepted Error: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InvalidArgumentException: Error in file : Invalid table number

Answer (score 0):

Some more details would be helpful; could you post the code you are using to access the Crystal Reports? There is definitely extra LogOnInfo that is needed for subreports...